# Converting File.stat!(file_path).mtime into local timezone in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: datetime, erlang, elixir

The file last modified time (mtime) seems to be based on UTC although the time tuple didn't return time zone.

How do I convert Erlang datetime to local time?

For instance, from `{{2017, 2, 6} {7, 3, 10}}` to `{{2017, 2, 5}, {23 , 3, 10}, "PST" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:calendar.universal_time_to_local_time/1` for this. For example, on an EST (UTC-5) time zone system:

```
iex(1)> :calendar.universal_time_to_local_time {{2017, 2, 6}, {7, 3, 10}}
{{2017, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 10}}
```

This doesn't return the timezone's name though.